# Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'. / buildTypes cant release

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, release

Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

[image]

honestly i tried everything :)

Comment: a small tip: even if you are able to generate it google play will reject com.eample , tr to change it before uploading to store.

Comment: `honestly i tried everything :)` Please add what you have tried so far?